# nginx: How to log multiple values of a http response header (custom)

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. I have a specific http response header which can appear more than once with different values (but with the same key). I want to extract all of these and log to nginx access log. What I found is that nginx only extracts the very first occurrence. Is there a way to get all values and log them?

I have a customer header called "x-extra" and this can appear multiple times like this in the response header from the servers behind the nginx:

```
X-Extra: value1
X-Extra: value2
X-Extra: value3
```

And I used "$upstream_http_x_extra" for extraction but what I got is "value1" only. Any way to get all these 3 values together (value1 value2 value3) in some fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at this point.